# Facebook Messaging API Checkbox Plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook

Can anyone tell me where to get the PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN??

I try to connect my website using Facebook's Messenger API, but I'm stuck trying to whitelist my domain because it requires a PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN.
Where can I find my PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/checkbox-plugin

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start reading at the very beginning, don´t just jump in at a random place in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/quick-start

Take a look at number 3: "Get a Page Access Token"